# PHP - Custom error handler doesn't invoke method

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm new to error handling technique. I just created a custom error handler by following this [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) similar to below,

```
<?php

public function customErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
 //log error
}

set_error_handler([$this, 'customErrorHandler'])

?>
```

This works fine.

When I set error types to false then my custom error handler method doesn't get invoked! I don't know what I'm missing since new to handling errors.

```
<?php

public function customErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
 //log error
}

set_error_handler([$this, 'customErrorHandler'], false)

?>
```

Comment: `$error_types` is what errors trigger the handler, you tell it `false` or none, what do you expect?

Comment: And actually `$error_types` expects an integer, one or more of the error constants, `false` is cast to `0`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php#refsect1-function.error-reporting-examples

Comment: @AbraCadaver I need to create a custom error handler that should always handle fata errors, but handle notice errors only if we are in debug mode. In production mode, all notice errors should not be displayed in the browser instead it should be logged.